# HttpPost [FromForm] also accepts query params

Tags: asp.net-core

To my despair, the below URL binds successfully and returns 200 OK.

```
https://myfakedomain.com/api/Submit?Email=test%40test.com&Name=fakeName
```

I just learned that my ASP.NET Core API accepts parameters to be submitted using query-strings. I do **not** want to allow users to submit sensitive data as part of the URL. Instead, I want to enforce my users to submit their info using FormData.

My endpoint looks like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Register([FromForm] RegisterDTO registerDTO)
{}
```

```
public class RegisterDTO
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I might add that submitting FormData also binds successfully.

Comment: Use [FromBody] instead and send the data in the BODY.

Comment: I've simplified my code for the purpose of this question, but the real endpoint also contains a IFormFile. I'll like to keep using FormData if possible.